# Jupyter Notebook Kernal Status: Disconnected randomly

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

So I am running jupyter notebook in a docker container and when I have connected to it. I am having Kernal Status: Connecting for like 3 minutes and then it says Kernal Status: disconnected. I know there's similar forums regarding this issue, and I have tried a majority of them and none seem to work for me. (maybe outdated) Any suggestions?

All my packages -

```
anyio                     4.0.0       
argon2-cffi               23.1.0      
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0      
asttokens                 2.4.0       
async-lru                 2.0.4       
attrs                     23.1.0      
Babel                     2.13.0      
backcall                  0.2.0       
beautifulsoup4            4.12.2      
bleach                    6.1.0       
certifi                   2023.7.22   
cffi                      1.16.0      
charset-normalizer        3.3.0       
comm                      0.1.4       
debugpy                   1.8.0       
decorator                 5.1.1       
defusedxml                0.7.1       
exceptiongroup            1.1.3       
executing                 2.0.0       
fastjsonschema            2.18.1      
idna                      3.4         
importlib-metadata        6.8.0       
importlib-resources       6.1.0       
ipykernel                 6.25.2      
ipython                   8.12.3      
ipython-genutils          0.2.0       
ipywidgets                8.1.1       
jedi                      0.19.1      
Jinja2                    3.1.2       
json5                     0.9.14      
jsonschema                4.19.1      
jsonschema-specifications 2023.7.1    
jupyter                   1.0.0       
jupyter-client            8.4.0       
jupyter-console           6.6.3       
jupyter-core              5.4.0       
jupyter-events            0.7.0       
jupyter-lsp               2.2.0       
jupyter-server            2.7.3       
jupyter-server-terminals  0.4.4       
jupyterlab                4.0.7       
jupyterlab-pygments       0.2.2       
jupyterlab-server         2.25.0      
jupyterlab-widgets        3.0.9       
MarkupSafe                2.1.3       
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6       
mistune                   3.0.2       
nbclient                  0.8.0       
nbconvert                 7.9.2       
nbformat                  5.9.2       
nest-asyncio              1.5.8       
notebook                  7.0.5       
notebook-shim             0.2.3       
overrides                 7.4.0       
packaging                 23.2        
pandocfilters             1.5.0       
parso                     0.8.3       
pexpect                   4.8.0       
pickleshare               0.7.5       
pip                       20.0.2      
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10      
platformdirs              3.11.0      
prometheus-client         0.17.1      
prompt-toolkit            3.0.39      
psutil                    5.9.5       
ptyprocess                0.7.0       
pure-eval                 0.2.2       
pycparser                 2.21        
Pygments                  2.16.1      
python-dateutil           2.8.2       
python-json-logger        2.0.7       
pytz                      2023.3.post1
PyYAML                    6.0.1       
pyzmq                     25.1.1      
qtconsole                 5.4.4       
QtPy                      2.4.0       
referencing               0.30.2      
requests                  2.31.0      
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4       
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1       
rpds-py                   0.10.6      
Send2Trash                1.8.2       
setuptools                45.2.0      
six                       1.16.0      
sniffio                   1.3.0       
soupsieve                 2.5         
stack-data                0.6.3       
terminado                 0.17.1      
tinycss2                  1.2.1       
tomli                     2.0.1       
tornado                   6.3.3       
traitlets                 5.11.2      
typing-extensions         4.8.0       
urllib3                   2.0.6       
wcwidth                   0.2.8       
webencodings              0.5.1       
websocket-client          1.6.4       
wheel                     0.34.2      
widgetsnbextension        4.0.9       
zipp                      3.17.0
```